Collapsed rows or columns in pivot table by default
When creating a Pivot Table chart in Apache Superset, is it possible to ensure that rows and columns are collapsed by default?
I have one column, two rows, and two metrics defined in my pivot table. Checking the options SHOW ROWS SUBTOTAL and SHOW COLUMNS SUBTOTAL adds the Subtotal row/column and enables the option to collapse or uncollapse individual rows/columns to either show all or only the subtotal.
However, by default, the pivot table shows all rows/columns while I'd prefer if the pivot table was collapsed by default and showed only subtotals.
Is there a way to achieve this?
